# magento extension installed then crashed my site

Tags: magento, crash

I installed a social extension pack, which worked fine, then it said I had upgrades and I did this and once it was done it crashed my site.
I cannot even get on it to fix the problem.

How do I get back into my site?

Comment: "Crashed the site" is pretty vague.  Without an error message, (from the browser page, log) no one here will be able to help you.

Comment: I installed a social media extention, then I upgraded a bunch of extentions. When I clicked refresh page at the bottom it then went to this page: http://bellaparisdesigns.com/store/admin/

Comment: no error, no nothing just a dead page, I cannot even get into the site to see what is wrong.

Comment: Clear all the caches and also Index all the modules

Comment: @BellaParis There's always an error.  I'd start googling on setting up PHP to properly log errors and/or set the PHP `display_errors.ini`

Comment: I think the issue is your store is in maintenance mode ... you have to delete `maintenance.flag` file from your server root

Answer (score 0):

First you have to download the module and delete the files from magento folder which are in the module.
and delete the maintenance file from magento root folder.

then check.

if not working then.

delete the cache from cache folder.
then find the database table of module and delete them.

or

you can also rename the package name of your magento module.